# Deactivate language fallback when translating (Python Django i18n)

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

I have an i18nized Python Django application. It currently uses two languages; German (DE) and French (FR).

I have all my keys (.po-/.mo-files) translated and ready in German, however for French, some are missing.

In the Django settings I specified 'de' as the `LANGUAGE_CODE`.

I can switch from one language to the other just fine without issues. The routing works fine and every other feature I need is handled by the Django Middleware.

However, in the current scenario when I switch from German to French, all the keys which are missing in French, just fallback to the German values. But I would like them to just default to their keys.

E.g.
**Current Scenario**
Sortiment (available in French) -> Assortiment
Gratis Lieferung (not available in French) -> Gratis Lieferung

**Expected Scenario**
Sortiment (available in French) -> Assortiment
Gratis Lieferung (not available in French) -> free.shipping.info

What would be a clean solution to solve this? I couldn't find anything in the Django documentation. I'd like to solve this without using additional plugins.

And one solution I could come up with, would be to just add all the missing keys in the french translations and have their values also be their keys but this doesn't feel right.

E.g. in `django.po`

```
msgid "searchsuggest.placeholder"
msgstr "searchsuggest.placeholder"
```

Another possible solution is to not set the `LANGUAGE_CODE` in the `settings.py` which works as I would want it for french, e.g. I go to `mypage.com/fr/` and all my translated keys are shown the correct corresponding value while untranslated keys are just shown as keys (See 'Expected Scenario'). But when I do this, the German version only shows the keys, no values. E.g.  I go to `mypage.com/` (German should be implicit) and this is what I see:

assortment.menu.title
free.shipping.info

**More information**

My `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    # app endpoints
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^cart', include('app.cart.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('app.infra.url.urls')),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)
```

My `settings.py`

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
LANGUAGES = [
    ('de', _('German')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
]
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    ../a/dir
]
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# And somewhere I use this
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
```

My jinja template global translation function:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class ViewExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(ViewExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.globals['trans'] = trans

# defaults back to german if not found
def trans(translation_key, **kwargs):
    translation = _(translation_key) % kwargs

    if translation == translation_key:
        # this only happens if my LANGUAGE_CODE is not set
        translation_logger.warning(f'Missing translation key "{translation_key}".')

    return translation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still happy if anyone has a "proper" solution for this but I ended up solving it with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# A simple script to make sure that all translation files contain all the msgids.
# If a msgid previously didn't exist in a file, it will be created with the msgstr set to the same as the msgid.

SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $0`
MSGIDS=`find $SCRIPTPATH -name "*.po" -type f -print0 | xargs grep -h msgid | sort | uniq | awk '{print $2}'`

find $SCRIPTPATH -name "*.po" -type f | while read FILE; do
    current_msgids=`grep -h msgid $FILE | awk '{print $2}'`
    for msg in $MSGIDS; do
        [[ $current_msgids =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$msg"($|[[:space:]]) ]] || printf "\nmsgid $msg\nmsgstr $msg\n" >> $FILE
    done
done
```

I just included this script before running `compilemessages` in our Makefile.

Comment: Have you found a "proper" solution for this? Can you kindly share it if you have. Thanks!

Comment: @fedosov unfortunately I never did. However the solution with this script worked well enough for our team.